# kerberos enabled Yarn - Unable to submit job with REST API

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have enabled kerberos with apache hadoop 2.7.1
With this I can run mapreduce example jars and also can write files in hdfs with REST API. 
But I am unable to submit the job with REST API.

May someone help me to check this problem, Thanks!

Comment: I am using bellow curl command to create new application id: curl --negotiate -ikv -u: -X POST 'http://<yarn-host>:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application'                                                    < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"AuthorizationException","message":"Unable to obtain user name, user not authenticated","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException"}}

Comment: Show the `-v` output.

Comment: Hi Michael-O, Thanks for quick reply . Please check I have updated the comment. Thanks

Comment: This is not the verbose output of curl. This is the server response.

Comment: It is the same output - * Connected to <yarn-host> () port 8088 (#0)
> POST /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: <yarn-host>:8088
> Accept: */*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it fails is because you have an ancient version of curl. Upgrade to the most recent one (7.49.0) and everything will work. SPNEGO have been made working from 7.38.0 and later.

Comment: ok, But I am able to get webhdfs delegation token with this command curl -s --negotiate -u : "http://<host>:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETDELEGATIONTOKEN&renewer=yarn"                                                    I can not upgrade the curl to that version as I am using centos 6.           Please can you suggest any java rest api client example which will authenticate with kerberos.

Comment: @aryan. You can, compile from source. It is straight forward.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I am just back from vacations. I will try it now, still I am confused with how I can authenticate with yarn api.

Comment: @aryan, You wrote about curl and I pointed you to your problem. The addon API is another issue.